# How to create explosion on collision

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am creating game, in this a helicopter fires a missile it hit the target and the target and missile disappears.I want to show some kind of explosion when they collide.I heard there is some sort of built in function for this
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out the [programmers guide?](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3aindex)  I would suggest looking into particle effects and even some of the open source games or code snippets provided by the community.  I think explosions are not generic enough where there is something built in, but you can use the particle effect engine to easily create one.

Something else to consider is using the [effects](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3aeffects), which actually look pretty cool.  You could probably do some kind of explosion by rippling a sprite of fire or something.